# Implementing a 100% Mathematica http server

Tags: webmathematica, licensing

I would like to dedicate a small machine to exclusively running a *Mathematica* kernel and use that kernel to read http requests arriving on port 80, treat them and send http responses back **without any web server or extra software of any kind**. Requests are to be treated in sequence (only 1 connection shall be supported at a time). Clearly *webMathematica* is an overkill here. Any ideas?

Comment: This usage is not permitted by the *Mathematica* licence: you need webMathematica, even if technically you don't. Practically speaking, it's not possible with *no extra software at all* since *Mathematica* has no facilities to work with TCP sockets, but you can use Java, a .Net language, or C to fill in the gaps.

Comment: It seems to me that using Mathematica to answer http requests is already "overkill."

Comment: There is now a built-in socket interface but it's undocumented and I have not sorted out a safe way of reading from the input stream.

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72551/reading-from-a-socket-stream

Comment: If you are using Mathematica 11.2 or later, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198548/54350).

Answer (score 8):

From Oleksandr's comment:

> This usage is not permitted by the Mathematica license: you need
>   webMathematica, even if technically you don't. Practically speaking,
>   it's not possible with no extra software at all since Mathematica has
>   no facilities to work with TCP sockets, but you can use Java, a .Net
>   language, or C to fill in the gaps.

The specific statement can be found in the [Mathematica License Agreement](http://www.wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica.html), under *Prohibited Uses*, section f:

> allowing access to the Product by any user other than Licensee,
>   including, without limitation, access to the Product via a web server,
>   which is only allowed pursuant to a valid webMathematica™ license
>   agreement;

and section j:

> using a password, activation key, or other means of accessing the
>   Software other than as specifically authorized by WRI;

Comment: What about locally hosting a web server?

Comment: @william. I'm not a lawyer so you have to think for yourself. If you're the only user section f could be interpreted as allowing it though section j suggests otherwise.

Comment: It seems the license agreement has been changed. webMathematica is not mentioned any more.

Answer (score 5):

This is node.js that creates a local server if you are experimenting.

Again this isn't legal to use on something other then  a local port.

```
var http = require('http');
var loc = "C:/Users/a/Desktop/node.m test";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;
    child = exec('"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/10.0/Math" -noprompt -script '+loc,
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        res.end(
          (stdout).replace(/\\n/g,"\n").slice(1,-3)
        );
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question because it is not a *Mathematica*-based solution.

Comment: @m_goldberg True but according to this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72551/reading-from-a-socket-stream There isn't one that works

Answer (score 1):

Yes (and using pure Mathematica or WolframEngine)

https://jerryi.github.io/tinyweb-mathematica/

Answer (score 0):

In the new 10.3 version, you can write in WlL the logic of your app/website and generate HTTP responses. See the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateHTTPResponse.html).

Comment: There are no new functions in 10.3 that will allow you to set up an HTTP server, as far as I know. That documentation page that you link to can't help.