# Reading from a socket stream

Tags: undocumented, streams, web-access

I noticed an undocumented socket package (`SocketLink`) in *Mathematica* (Using version 10, not sure when it was actually added) and wrote a barebones HTTP responder using it:

```
<<SocketLink`
host = "localhost";
port = 9999;
eol = "\r\n";
helloHTML = 
  "<html><head><title>Hello world!</title></head><body>Hello world!</body></html>";
response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"<>eol<>
    "Content-length: "<>ToString[StringLength[helloHTML<>eol]]<>eol<>eol<>
    helloHTML<>eol;
handler[streams_] := Module[{
        inStream = streams[[1]],
        outStream = streams[[2]],
        req = {},
        reqString
    },
    While[!MatchQ[req, {___, 13, 10, 13, 10}],
        AppendTo[req, BinaryRead[inStream]];
    ];
    Close[inStream];
    reqString = FromCharacterCode[req];
    (* print request *)
    Print[reqString];
    BinaryWrite[outStream, ToCharacterCode[response]];
    Close[outStream];
];

s = CreateServerSocket[port]
ser = CreateAsynchronousServer[s, handler]
```

The issue is that I have no way of telling when there is no more content in the input stream. This is a problem because if I read once byte beyond this the kernel crashes. I get around it in the above code by reading each character individually and using pattern matching to detect when the request ends (at "\r\n\r\n"):

```
While[!MatchQ[req, {___, 13, 10, 13, 10}],
    AppendTo[req, BinaryRead[inStream]];
];
```

This is will work with properly formed requests but if the request is malformed the kernel crash is unavoidable as far as I can see.  I realize implementing an HTTP server in *Mathematica* is a silly endeavour but I would like to know if there is a way of detecting the "end" of a socket stream for other potentially nontrivial uses of `SocketLink`.

Answer (score 9):

I was playing around `SocketLink` too. (And tried implementing a "pure" Mathematica server too!). About the OP's question, on my Windows 8.1 64bit, Doing more `BinaryRead[inStream]` than necessary will not crash the kernel, it will just wait for input, which blocks the main link. My workaround for this is using `TimeConstrained`:

```
While[True,
      TimeConstrained[AppendTo[req, BinaryRead[inStream]], 0.01, Break[]];
     ]
```

This is surely not the best way to go, but unfortunately I don't know C++ enough to modify the source code of `SocketLink`'s libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Beginning with Mathematica 10 there is a new function `ReadString`
to get the (current) available data from an open socket connection by setting `EndOfBuffer` as terminator.

But there has to be at least one finished read to the stream before `ReadString[socket, EndOfBuffer]` will return the next chunk.

Basic stream function `StreamPosition`, `SetStreamPosition` will also work.

Hint:
try `OpenRead`, `OpenWrite` on `SocketObject` creates underlying stream objects.